# Authorization header disappears in a request with Swift

Tags: swift, http-headers, jwt

### Preamble

I want to call the API using JWT authentication with Swift.
But return the HTTP response code 401 from the server.

I’m sorry, I'm not very good in English.

### Source code

```swift
let url = URL(string: HOST + urlString)

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
if let key = store.key {
    request.addValue("JWT " + key.token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
}

print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)
// Optional(["Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "JWT {token}"])

let task: URLSessionTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
    // Something code
}

task.resume()
```

As mentioned in the comment, the output by `print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)` is `Optional(["Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "JWT {token}"])`.
Therefore, at this time, it can be seen that Atuhorization is included in the header.

### What I tried

When I used the same token to call it with API Tester (which is a Chrome extension), it was fine.

I did a debug using the nc command.
The following two lines have been added.

```swift
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("fuga", forHTTPHeaderField: "hoge")
```

The results are as follows.

```
$ nc -l 8000
GET {URL} HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Type: application/json
hoge: fuga
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: {Client agent name}
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

This way, the other keys work, but only the Authorization key fails.

### Supplement information

Version information.
Xcode: 11.5
Swift: 5.2.4

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the documentation [JWT documentation](https://jwt.io/introduction/), you have to use the "bearer" type of token so something like this:

```
request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I changed it to "bearer" but it didn't work. In the present circumstances, the "Authorization" key cannot be sent to the server side.  I don't think the JWT specification has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: It should look something like this when print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields) is called

Optional(["Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"])


Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes I can. However, only "Authorization" key does not exist in the server side.